# Compare two lines in CSV, remove one line based on certain criteria

Tags: csv, powershell, compare, row

Using PowerShell (I'm relatively new to coding), I'm trying to take a large CSV file with 26 columns and trying to manipulate data when certain fields have duplicate data... but keep all of the data if the field isn't duplicate.

Example data:

```
Name,DOB,Address,PhoneNo,FaveSport,FaveTeam,FavePlayer, 
Nick,1/1/01,123 4th,123-456-7890,,, 
Nick,1/1/01,,,Hockey,Red Wings,Lidstrom
Calvin,2/2/02,456 7th,555-867-5309,Football,Lions,Megatron
Mickey,3/3/03,999 Yankee Way,111-222-3333,,,
Mickey,3/3/03,,,Baseball,Yankees,Mantle
```

In the scenario above, I want to keep the first 4 columns of Nick's top line and the last 3 columns of Nick's second, nearly duplicate line.  It will always be the same way with the top line having the appropriate first 4 columns and the second line (if there is a second line - there is sometimes only 1 like Calvin, in which case we keep the whole line) having the data we want in the final 3 columns.

So, the data we want after we're done is

```
Name,DOB,Address,PhoneNo,FaveSport,FaveTeam,FavePlayer,
Nick,1/1/01,123 4th,123-456-7890,Hockey,Red Wings,Lidstrom 
Calvin,2/2/02,456 7th,555-867-5309,Football,Lions,Megatron
Mickey,3/3/03,999 Yankee Way,111-222-3333,Baseball,Yankees,Mantle
```

I'm completely at a loss as to how to compare the first x columns of one line with another to check for "duplicates" and then write those first x fields of the first line and the last x fields of the second line to a new document...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Trying to be the hero for my wife who currently has to do this by manually copy/pasting over and over on a 5k+ row Excel doc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Hashtable` to store the first row, and then if another row with the same name appears, copy only the columns that have actual values:

```
$Data = @'
Name,DOB,Address,PhoneNo,FaveSport,FaveTeam,FavePlayer, 
Nick,1/1/01,123 4th,123-456-7890,,, 
Nick,1/1/01,,,Hockey,Red Wings,Lidstrom
Calvin,2/2/02,456 7th,555-867-5309,Football,Lions,Megatron
Mickey,3/3/03,999 Yankee Way,111-222-3333,,,
Mickey,3/3/03,,,Baseball,Yankees,Mantle
'@|ConvertFrom-Csv

# Set up a hashtable to keep track of distinct player names
$Players = @{}

foreach($Row in $Data) {
    if(-not $Players.ContainsKey($Row.Name))
    {
        # First row with that player name
        $Players[$Row.Name] = $Row
    }
    else
    {
        # We've already read the first row for this guy
        foreach($Property in $Row.psobject.Properties)
        {
            # Check each property for whether it has a value
            if($Property.Value)
            {
                # Overwrite previous property value 
                $Players[$Row.Name]."$($Property.Name)" = $Property.Value
            }
        }
    }
}

# Print final results
$Players.Values |Format-Table
```

Comment: Great solution you have here!

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want the last columns, and expanding on the great work from @Mathias, you can do this:

```
$Data = @'
Name,DOB,Address,PhoneNo,FaveSport,FaveTeam,FavePlayer, 
Nick,1/1/01,123 4th,123-456-7890,,, 
Nick,1/1/01,,,Hockey,Red Wings,Lidstrom
Calvin,2/2/02,456 7th,555-867-5309,Football,Lions,Megatron
Mickey,3/3/03,999 Yankee Way,111-222-3333,,,
Mickey,3/3/03,,,Baseball,Yankees,Mantle
'@|ConvertFrom-Csv

# Set up a hashtable to keep track of distinct player names
$Players = @{}

# Make a named list of the columns you're wanting to keep from the second rows
$columns = @("FaveSport","FaveTeam","FavePlayer")

foreach($Row in $Data) {
    if(-not $Players.ContainsKey($Row.Name))
    {
        # First row with that player name
        $Players[$Row.Name] = $Row
    }
    else
    {
        # Check just the named columns that you want to keep the good values for
        foreach($item in $columns)
        {
            # Check each property for whether it has a value
            if (-not $Players[$Row.Name]."$($item)".Value){
                $Players[$Row.Name]."$($item)" = $Row.FavePlayer
            }
        }
    }
}

# Print final results
$Players.Values |Format-Table
```

Basically you're just checking and pulling in only the columns you want.